# Get Terminal Number

Tags: terminal, zsh, console

I'm making a mini welcomer script in `.zshrc`.
The script is ( I want to replace `$TTYNUMBERGOESHERE` with the tty number, but with a variable to make it automatically update on every terminal);

```
clear
echo "Welcome to Mehmet Akif's Linux!"
echo
echo " * $USER on MadLinux."
echo " * Using $TTYNUMBERGOESHERE."
echo
echo "Type 'startx' to start graphical user interface."
echo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `tty` command:

```
clear
echo "Welcome to Mehmet Akif's Linux!"
echo
echo " * $LOGNAME on MadLinux."
echo " * Using $(basename $(tty))"
echo
echo "Type 'startx' to start graphical user interface."
echo
```

Or, a little more tidy:

```bsh
clear
printf '%s\n\n%s on MadLinux.\nUsing %s\n\n%s\n\n' \
       "Welcome to Mehmet Akif's Linux!" \
       "$LOGNAME" \
       "$(basename $(tty))" \
       "Type 'startx' to start graphical user interface."
```

Or, with a HERE doc:

```
clear
cat <<EoF
Welcome to Mehmet Akif's Linux!

$LOGNAME on MadLinux.
Using $(basename $(tty))

"Type 'startx' to start graphical user interface."
EoF
```

Actually, in `zsh` there is an even simpler way of getting the tty name: the `$TTY` variable. So you could just use:

```
clear
cat <<EoF
Welcome to Mehmet Akif's Linux!

$USER on MadLinux.
Using "${TTY#/dev/}"

"Type 'startx' to start graphical user interface."
EoF
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, thanks. I forgot the OP mentioned `.zshrc`.

Comment: zsh sets `$USERNAME`. `$USER` is set by some `login` programs. `$LOGNAME` is more standard.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas huh. For some reason, I wasn't aware of `$LOGNAME`.thanks.

Comment: `${TTY#/dev/}` may be preferable to `$TTY:t` so you get `tty1`, `pts/1`, `ttyS0`... instead of `tty1`, `1`, `ttyS0`.